# Standalone Android HTML5 App

Tags: android, web-applications, html5-apps

Is there an equivalent meta tag to the iOS tag that makes a html page on an Android device act like a standalone App?
eg:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that is not an "iOS tag". It is mobile Safari tag. iOS is an operating system. Safari is a browser. Browsers view Web pages. And, if Apple allows third-party browsers on iOS, other browsers may or may not be able to interpret your "iOS tag".

On most operating systems (that are not themselves one big Web browser), the pattern is the same. A browser may support such tags, while other browsers may not, even for the same OS.

On Android, [Chrome M31 Beta apparently supports this](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen), using a similar `<meta>` tag. Whether other browsers support this, I cannot say.